# Compass UI and Needle

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, expression-blend

I want to make some compass app and want to show needle deflection according to lat long of user. But I am unable to understand how I can give proper shape as compass. Currently I am using this code to show Compass.

```
 <Ellipse StrokeThickness="2" x:Name="circle" Width="400" Height="400" 
                  Margin="0,90,0,0" Fill="Black">
                <Ellipse.Stroke>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource PhoneAccentColor}" />
                </Ellipse.Stroke>
            </Ellipse>

 <Line  x:Name="line" X1="240" Y1="350" X2="240" Y2="270"  Stroke="{StaticResource  PhoneForegroundBrush}" StrokeThickness="4"></Line>
```

You can see my poor UI with this one code.

[image]

And I want this kind little bit better UI with atleast needle stuff like this.

[image]

I hope some one can help me in this UI Shape

Comment: I think you could use an arrow image and rotate it according to lat/long or what you please...

Comment: Maybe this [MSDN Magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj190804.aspx) article helps. With code.

Comment: Thanks marco for your comment. But Can you please tell me How I Can rotate that. Can You Please Come With Any Example or Reference. Your Help Will Be Highly Appreciated

Comment: @HenkHolterman answer is really what you need. Inside article you'll find code to "rotate" if you need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will give you your desired example arrow, for your specific phone page, with the centre at the bottom so you can just place it on your compass.

It also has a named member called `MyTransform` you can simply set the angle of the Rotation property (0 = North, 180 = South etc).

```
        <Path Data="M87.026947,24.16836 L102.66625,48.669857 L94.666451,48.669857 L94.666451,84.674995 L78.666855,84.674995 L78.666855,48.669857 L70.667053,48.669857 z" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="60.498" Stretch="Fill" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="32" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,1" Margin="0,0,208,191.502">
            <Path.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform x:Name="MyTransform" Rotation="0" ScaleX="2.91" TranslateX="-16" TranslateY="-61" ScaleY="3.4"/>
            </Path.RenderTransform>
            <Path.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FEFEFEFE" Offset="0.58"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FEE22828" Offset="0.604"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FEE64C4C" Offset="0.795"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FEFFFFFF" Offset="0.826"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Path.Fill>
        </Path>
```

### Example Image:

[image]

*It was authored in Expression blend by importing your sample image and drawing over the top. Then the scaling altered to match your actual page size (as the bitmap shown was not 1:1 scale).*

To use this simple set rotation from code to the desired angle

### e.g. as per your snippet:

```
    void DrawCompass()
    {
       MyTransform.Rotation = 0.0;   // North
       MyTransform.Rotation = 180.0; // South
       MyTransform.Rotation = 90.0;  // East
       MyTransform.Rotation = 270.0; // West
       // Or any other angle in between
       // or simply bind the Rotation property to an angle property on your viewmodel
    }
```

Comment: I am following your code. Please see my comments and code on this URL.
http://snipt.org/vmX1

Comment: Added to sample as per your snippet and updated naming to simplify the transform. New image added. It is not perfect and needs tweaking (the arrow is not quite in the centre), but you get the idea.

Comment: I have tested the your new updated code. I can handle the UI now and will do the tweaking. But can you please tell me how I can set the angle as I am doing earlier.

 line.X2 = line.X1 - (200 * Math.Sin(MathHelper.ToRadians(100)));
 line.Y2 = line.Y1 - (200 * Math.Cos(MathHelper.ToRadians(100)));

Answer (score 3):

There are two parts to this.

In the first instance you will need to define an arrow shape. The following is some XAML that does this:

```
    <system:String x:Key="ArrowData">
        M7.7314458,3.052578
        L13.998698,9.3155994
        L13.998698,14.038256
        L9.4029951,9.445858
        L9.4029951,18.633959
        L6.059896,18.633959
        L6.059896,9.445858
        L1.4641927,14.038256
        L1.4641927,9.3155994
        z
    </system:String>
```

You can use it like this:

```
<Path Data="{StaticResource ArrowData}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,1.0" Stretch="Uniform" UseLayoutRounding="False" Fill="Black"/>
```

In the second instance you will need to rotate this so that it points in the right direction:

```
<Path Data="{StaticResource ArrowData}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,1.0" Stretch="Uniform" UseLayoutRounding="False" Fill="Black">
    <Path.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <RotateTransform Angle="180"/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </Path.RenderTransform>
</Path>
```

Obviously in this case it will be displayed upside down and fixed, but if you bind the `RotateTransform` `Angle` to your compass heading it will point in the right direction.

Comment: Hi. I tried your code. And I am giving hard coded angle in my xaml instead of 180 to 100. But It Showing nothing on Page.. :(

Comment: @ArslanPervaiz - I don't know. The code should work. Try removing the rotation altogether in the first instance to make sure you get an arrow. Alternatively add the rotation to your line code to see if you can get that working.

Comment: @ArslanPervaiz - "The snippet you're looking for has either been deleted by its owner or it never existed to begin with."

Answer (score 0):

Use the BlockArrow shape from the Blend SDK. There is no need to ever draw your own arrows again. Then simply rotate the control based on the angle you wish to show. You might have to transform the origin as well so it rotates around the end instead of the middle.